# android studio updating and problem in gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Today i updated my Android studio plugin version to 3.2.0, after that I set the gradle build to offline mode, but that do not build gradle correctly, can anybody help me in this issue?

The error is:

> ((No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 available for offline mode.))

Comment: try online mode. once it builds completely in online mode offline should work as well.

Comment: simply update Android Studio to `3.2.1` and build the project once.